# Room relationship matching multiple columns

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a relationship between entities that should look like this:

Overview -> has many -> Category -> has many -> Transaction

Category should be included in Overview if Category.overviewId == Overview.id. I'm pretty sure I should be able to achieve this with the @Relation annotation, something like:

```
@Relation(parentColumn = 'id', entityColumn = 'overviewId')
List<Category> categories;
```

Within the Category entity I then want to include any Transaction where Transaction.overviewId == Category.overviewId && Transaction.categoryId == Category.categoryId. This is the part that I'm struggling with, as the @Relation annotation only seems to be able to take 1 column into account. I think I want something like:

```
@Relation(parentColumn = {'overviewId','categoryId'}, entityColumn = {'overviewId','categoryId'})
List<Transaction> transactions;
```

But this doesnt seem to be a valid way of doing things.
Does anyone know how I should achieve this?
I guess ultimately I want to be able to observe a query that will update whenever a relevant Overview, Category, or Transaction is updated, so embedding the Categories and Transactions in the Overview seems like the best way to go, but if there is a better way it'd be great to hear it.

Comment: If you are affected by this please give this issue an upvote: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64247765

Answer (score 6):

Had same problem, came up with @Transaction

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM store_table WHERE userId = :userId AND storeId = :storeId")
fun getStore(storeId:String, userId:String): StoreDb?

@Query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE userId = :userId AND storeId = :storeId")
fun getProducts(storeId:String, userId:String):List<ProdusctsDb>

@Transaction
fun getStoreWithProducts(storeId:String, userId:String): StoreWithProductsDb{
    val storeDb: StoreDb = getStore(storeId,userId) ?: return null
    val products = getProducts(storeId,userId)
    return  StoreWithProductsDb(storeDb, products)
}
```

Where StoreWithProductsDb is usual data class

```
data class StoreWithProductsDb(val storeDb: StoreDb, val products: List<ProductsDb>)
```

PS: just adopted example all names are random